# Append item in list of lists when all dimensions of all lists are unknown in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am trying to write python code that organizes n-dimensional data into bins.

To do this, I'm initializing a list of empty lists using the following function, which takes an array with the number of bins for each dimension as an argument:

```
def empties(b):

    invB = np.flip(b, axis=0)
    empty = []
    for b in invB:
        build = deepcopy(empty)
        empty = []
        for i in range(0,b):
            empty.append(build)

    return np.array(empty).tolist() # workaround to clear list references
```

For example, for two dimensional data with 3 bins along each dimension, the following should be expected:

Input:

```
empties([3,3])
```

Output:

```
[ [[],[],[]], [[],[],[]], [[],[],[]] ]
```

I'd like to append objects to this list of lists.  This is easy if the dimensions are known.  If I wanted to append an object to the above list at position (1,2), I could use:

```
bins = empties([3,3])

obj = Object()
bins[1][2].append(obj)
```

However, I want this to work for any unknown number of dimensions and number of bins.  Therefore, I cannot use "[ ][ ][ ]..." notation to define the list index.  Lists do not take lists or tuples for the index, so this is not an option.  Additionally, I cannot use a numpy array because all lists can be different lengths.

Is there any solution for how to set an element of a list based on a dynamic number of indices?

Ideally, if lists could take a list as the index, I would do this:

```
idx = some_function_that_gets_bin_numbers()

bins[idx].append(obj)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean... You could implement a custom `__getitem__` on a custom class, (like numpy does)

but assuming you can't, something like:

```
def append_md(lst, idx, value):
    for i in idx:
        lst = lst[i]
    lst.append(value)

append_md(bins, idx, obj)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This post is exactly what I needed - clears up how I should be using list references.  I just wanted to note that the third line should read "lst = lst[i]"

Answer (score 1):

You can apply indices to a nested array iteratively like this:

```
reduce((lambda a, e: a[e]), index_list, nested_list)
```

if `nested_list = [0, 1, [[[2], [3]], 4], 5]`, and `index_list = [2, 0, 1]`, the above line will return `[3]`.